# Filtering dataset based on a threshold does not print correct output name

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, shiny

I have the following code to analyze quantitative PCR data in large numbers, which I later developed to a shiny app. So, the data file contains two separate datasets namely `Amplification_data` and `Multicomponent_data`. The `Amplification_data` contains several columns of which two are the most important for me namely, Well which corresponds to the samples, and `Delta.Rn` indicating the baseline signature value. In the `Multicomponent_data`, there are different variables like `FAM`, `VIC`, `ABY`, etc. that indicate the value of each dye during each PCR cycle. This dataset contains an additional column named `Well.Position`. My goal is to select the samples that are above a threshold value of `0.25` based on the `Delta.Rn` column. Using this threshold, I filter out the samples for each variable in the `Multicomponent_data` and output those in a table from this table in the code `data_amp_without_nad_abovethreshold`. I want to print the `Well.Position` instead of Well in the final result table. And the `Well.Position` is only available in this table in the code `data_mult_long_wells_abovethreshold`. If I put this in the final part of the code, then it does print the `Well.Position` but then the number of entries does not change with different dataset.

My question is: how can I change the code so that it prints out the `Well.Position` for any dataset? Also, how can I have separate columns for each variable i.e. `FAM`, `VIC`, `ABY` in the final output table showing the samples passing the threshold?

The main two data files (Amplification and Multicomponent) look like below:

```
Well    Cycle   Target Name Rn  Delta Rn
1   1   NAD 0.783   -0.001
1   2   NAD 0.784   -0.001
1   3   NAD 0.790   0.005
1   4   NAD 0.785   -0.000
1   5   NAD 0.786   -0.000

Well    Well Position   Cycle   Variable    Value
1         A1    1   ROX 87,775.805
2         A2    1   ROX 93,415.906
3         A3    1   ROX 78,181.969
4         A4    1   ROX 80,889.961
5         A5    1   ROX 82,003.539
1         A1    1   FAM 289,678.656
2         A2    1   FAM 309,213.625
3         A3    1   FAM 240,776.391
4         A4    1   FAM 258,521.719
5         A5    1   FAM 259,155.359
1         A1    1   VIC 196,214.188
2         A2    1   VIC 207,413.062
3         A3    1   VIC 167,448.625
4         A4    1   VIC 175,989.156
5         A5    1   VIC 177,358.594
1         A1    1   ABY 68,761.781
2         A2    1   ABY 74,910.500
3         A3    1   ABY 51,908.082
4         A4    1   ABY 60,656.004
5         A5    1   ABY 60,389.473
```

The code is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotlyExtra)

file<-"data.txt"
data<-read.table(file,sep="!",header=F,blank.lines.skip=F) 
linesforresults<-grep("[",data$V1,fixed=T)
print(as.character(data$V1[linesforresults]))

#amplification data
if("[Amplification Data]"%in%as.character(data$V1[linesforresults])){
  #assuming order is: amplification, multicom, results
  whichamp<-which(as.character(data$V1[linesforresults])=="[Amplification Data]")
  data_amp<-read.table(file,
                       skip=linesforresults[whichamp],
                       nrows=linesforresults[whichamp+1]-linesforresults[whichamp]-4,
                       sep="\t",
                       header=T,
                       blank.lines.skip=F)
  print("[Amplification Data]")
  print(head(data_amp))
  print(tail(data_amp))
}
#multicomponent data
if("[Multicomponent Data]"%in%as.character(data$V1[linesforresults])){
  #assuming order is: amplification, multicom, results
  whichmul<-which(as.character(data$V1[linesforresults])=="[Multicomponent Data]")
  data_mult<-read.table(file,
                        skip=linesforresults[whichmul],
                        nrows=linesforresults[whichmul+1]-linesforresults[whichmul]-4,
                        sep="\t",
                        header=T,
                        blank.lines.skip=F)
  #Numerical values read in with a thousand , seperator
  data_mult[c("ROX", "FAM","ABY","VIC")] <- lapply(data_mult[c("ROX", "FAM","ABY","VIC")], function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x)))
  
  print("[Multicomponent Data]")
  print(head(data_mult))
  print(tail(data_mult))
}

#ROX, FAM, ABY and VIC into 1
data_mult_long<-reshape2::melt(data_mult,
                               id.vars=c("Well","Well.Position","Cycle"),
                               measure.vars=c("ROX","ABY","FAM", "VIC")
)
dev.off()

ggplot2::ggplot(data_amp,ggplot2::aes(Cycle, Delta.Rn,group=interaction(Well,Target.Name)),col=Target.Name)+
  ggplot2::geom_line(ggplot2::aes(col=Target.Name))+
  ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(col=Target.Name))+
  ggplot2::geom_hline(yintercept=0.25, linetype="dashed",color = "red", size=1) #threshold at 0.25 for this test

ggplot2::ggplot(data_mult_long,ggplot2::aes(Cycle, value,group=interaction(Well)),col=Well)+
  ggplot2::geom_line(ggplot2::aes(col=Well))+
  ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(col=Well))+
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~variable,ncol=2)


data_amp_2<-data_amp
data_mult_long2<-data_mult_long[which(
  data_mult_long$Cycle==max(data_mult_long$Cycle,na.rm=T)
  &data_mult_long$variable=="FAM"),-which(colnames(data_mult_long)=="Cycle")]
merged_amp_mult_long_p1<-merge(data_amp_2,data_mult_long2,by="Well")

data_mult_long2<-data_mult_long[which(
  data_mult_long$Cycle==max(data_mult_long$Cycle,na.rm=T)
  &data_mult_long$variable=="VIC"),-which(colnames(data_mult_long)=="Cycle")]
merged_amp_mult_long_p2<-merge(data_amp_2,data_mult_long2,by="Well")

data_mult_long2<-data_mult_long[which(
  data_mult_long$Cycle==max(data_mult_long$Cycle,na.rm=T)
  &data_mult_long$variable=="ROX"),-which(colnames(data_mult_long)=="Cycle")]
merged_amp_mult_long_p3<-merge(data_amp_2,data_mult_long2,by="Well")

data_mult_long2<-data_mult_long[which(
  data_mult_long$Cycle==max(data_mult_long$Cycle,na.rm=T)
  &data_mult_long$variable=="ABY"),-which(colnames(data_mult_long)=="Cycle")]
merged_amp_mult_long_p4<-merge(data_amp_2,data_mult_long2,by="Well")

merged_amp_mult_long<-rbind(merged_amp_mult_long_p1,merged_amp_mult_long_p2,merged_amp_mult_long_p3,merged_amp_mult_long_p4)
merged_amp_mult_long2<-merged_amp_mult_long
merged_amp_mult_long2$delta<-c(NA,diff(merged_amp_mult_long2$Delta.Rn))


##################################################################################
#get values in delta.ct above threshold (0.25)
#and show multi-comp or delta-delta plot for that
data_amp_without_nad<-data_amp[which(!data_amp$Target.Name=="NAD"),]
data_amp_without_nad_abovethreshold<-data_amp_without_nad[which(data_amp_without_nad$Delta.Rn>0.25),]
wells_abovethreshold<-unique(data_amp_without_nad_abovethreshold$Well)

data_mult_long_wells_abovethreshold<-data_mult_long[which(data_mult_long$Well%in%wells_abovethreshold),]
data_filtered <- data_mult_long_wells_abovethreshold %>%
  filter(variable %in% c("FAM", "ABY", "ROX", "VIC"))
p <- ggplot2::ggplot(data_filtered,ggplot2::aes(Cycle, value,colour=variable,group=interaction(Well)),col=Well)+
  ggplot2::geom_line(ggplot2::aes())+
  ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes())+
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~variable,ncol=2)


print(p)
samples <- unique(data_mult_long_wells_abovethreshold$Well.Position)
print(samples)
```

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: If your question is about filtering samples from one frame based on its values and another frame, why do we need the [tag:shiny] tag and `ggplot(..)` code?

Comment: Because it will be used routinely and I want to deploy it as an app for visualizing and printing the samples above a threshold which can be downloaded.

Comment: Your data is not really consistent: `data_mult` looks like it's in long format, but your code looks like it loads in wide format, fixes the numbers, then pivots to long ... though your long data has the numbers as formatted strings. Further, you reference `Multicomponent_data` but work on `data_mult` and `data_mult_long`, reference columns like `Well.Position` but provide data with `Well Position` (space). Finally, it would really help to have the literal expected output given this sample.

Comment: (BTW, thank you for replacing images with data. The embedded spaces make it a little less-easy to import, but far better than images. Thanks!)